# no matches found when using associative arrays in zsh

Tags: zsh, array, associative-array

I am encountering `no matches found` when using map in zsh:

```
#!/bin/zsh

declare -A map=(["8761"]="Eureka服务" ["11001"]="用户微服务")
```

Why would this happen, and how can I fix it? This is the error:

```
~/source/dolphin/dolphin-scripts/bash/tool on  master! ⌚ 20:57:52
$ ./batch-terminal-process.sh
./batch-terminal-process.sh:14: no matches found: [8761]=Eureka服务
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zsh` doesn't support the `typeset -A array([key]=value ...)` syntax from `ksh` and `bash`.

Instead of that, you should simply initialize an associative array by alternating keys and values:

```
% declare -A map=(8761 "Eureka服务" 11001 "用户微服务")
% echo ${map[8761]}
Eureka服务
```

Answer (score 3):

As Uncle Billy said, this syntax was not understood by zsh.

However, support was added in zsh >= 5.5 (see [changelog](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html)) and your snippet now works.